# Уведомление при переносе комментариев в чат | Notification when comments are moved to chat

Tags: предложение, чат, уведомления

Сейчас, насколько я знаю, если модератор переносит комментарии в чат, их авторам не выводится никакого уведомления. Поскольку недавно выяснилось, что в чат могут заходить участники, не говорящие по русски, и необоснованно отмечать сообщения оскорбительными, хотелось бы иметь возможность вовремя перенести информацию куда-то в безопасное место. В комментариях часто содержится важная "промежуточная" информация до момента формирования окончательного ответа, не хотелось бы ее терять.

Предлагаю сделать, чтобы при переносе комментариев в чат всем затронутым участникам приходило уведомление. Если администрация не может разобраться с правилами чата, позвольте людям держаться подальше от всего этого.

---

As far as i know, there's no notification when moderator moves comments to chat. Since it was recently discovered that foreign speakers can come to chat and incorrectly mark posts as inappropriate, i want to have opportunity to move important data out of it. Comments often contain important intermidiate data until final answer is written, which i'd like not to get burninated for no reason.

I suggest that, when comments are moved to chat, all affected users will be notified. If administration can't make chat work properly, let users stay away from it.

Comment: Но комментарии тоже могут быть удалены.

Comment: Когда мы не можем решить одну проблему и решаем десяток мелких костылями и подпорками. Это не первая проблема, которая имеет родителем 'флагают в чате', там бы и решать.

Comment: @Qwertiy но только модераторами Ru SO. А не всеми модераторами SE.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, ещё и авторами комментариев.

Comment: Кстати, уведомления, вроде, должны быть? По крайней мере тем, кого зовут в перенесённых комментариях. Ну и автору сообщения из-за нового комментария под ним. Нет? Хотя.. наверное, нет...

Comment: Вы смешиваете две проблемы - уведомление о создании чата и не умение пользоваться флагами в чатах. Временные чаты которые создает система (или модератор) мало кого интересуют и вы точно успеете дополнить ответ необходимой информацией.

Comment: @FoggyFinder насколько я понял недавнюю проблему в чате, кто-то массово ставил флаги на нормальные сообщения. Речь не просто о неумении. И нет гарантии, что в других чатах кто-то не захочет так же повеселиться, если временные чаты тоже видимы в общем списке чатов Ru SO.

Comment: "Поскольку недавно выяснилось, что в чат могут заходить участники, не говорящие по русски, и необоснованно отмечать сообщения оскорбительными, ". Это совершенно не так. Кто конкретно ставил флаги выяснить так и не удалось.

Comment: Нет, это проблема не недавняя - уже были случаи массовых флагов (один даже устраивали специально =))

Comment: " И нет гарантии, что в других чатах кто-то не захочет так же повеселиться, если временные чаты тоже видимы в общем списке чатов Ru SO" Гарантия есть - если кто-то захочет повеселиться в малоактивном чате то этот кто-то очень быстро будет обнаружен.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Возможно это так. Но все же было бы спокойнее знать, что комментарии перенесли в чат.

Comment: @GreenDragon главная проблема, что не говорящие по русски пользователи с правами модератора могут принимать флаги. Кто именно ставит флаги, второстепенно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight , с этим(прием флагов) - согласен.